# Change color of the calendar icon in Semantic ui react input

Tags: css, reactjs, semantic-ui

I'm using semantic ui react for my date input. I need to change the calendar icon color of the input. Is it possible ?
here is my code

```
<Input
  id="fromDate"
  name="fromDate"
  type="date"
  value={state.fromDate}
  onChange={onHandleChange}
  placeholder="Date"
  className="custom-date-input"
 />
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if there is a better way to do it with other specific colors, but you can use filters on it. You just have to select it with CSS
`.custom-date-input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator { filter: invert(); }` like this.
Also, here is a [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-haslett-q7lhsc?file=/src/styles.css:115-209) of codesandbox where I implemented it, there I tried to get the color you have in the placeholder with filters. So take a look at it, and I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you it works.

.custom-date-input>input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
 filter: opacity(0.7) invert() !important;
  }